# Python :ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am accessing a json data and want to convert it in pandas dataframe.
Unfortunately, an error occurred when `json.loads(req.text)`

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Below is my code.

```
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
          "Origin": "https://www.idx.co.id"}
req = requests.get("https://www.idx.co.id/Portals/0/StaticData/HomeHtml/data.js",
                  headers=HEADERS)
stocks = json.loads(req.text)
columns = ['code', 'name']

df = pd.DataFrame([{k: v for k,v in d.items() if k in columns}
              for d in stocks, columns = columns)
```

Comment: Post req.text please

Comment: JavaScript is not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually receiving a JSON, but a Javascript file. Applying a simple regular expression matching all the data between `[]` you can achieve the desired result.

```py
import requests
import json
import re

req = requests.get("https://www.idx.co.id/Portals/0/StaticData/HomeHtml/data.js")
content = re.findall(r"= (\[.*?\]);", req.text)
data = json.loads(content[0])
print(data)
```

Edit: an useful website to test python regexp is https://pythex.org/

Comment: Thanks. Can you further explain `re.findall(r"= (\[.*?\]);", req.text)` and the difference json and javascript?

Comment: Sure. It searches all data after an = and inside parenthesis before ;. For example applied to `this_variable = [{"somedata": 1}];` the result will be `[{"somedata": 1}]` (which is JSON serializable). For further details and to test it against different strings see the website I added to my answer.

Comment: JavaScript is a programming language. JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, which is a data format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I want to understand your first sentence where it is not JSON but javascript file. Can you differentiate how json and javascript in term of format?